# PyInstaller win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Tags: anaconda, pyinstaller, environment, pywin32

While using PyInstaller (dev version 4.0.dev0+8196c57ab), produced an `OSError: [WinError 2] 'The system cannot find the file specified.'`

- Python version: 3.7
- GUI: PySide2 5.13.0
- Other packages: lxml, BeautifulSoup, Matplotlib (with dependencies like numpy), Pandas, pypiwin32, reportlab, Theano
- Anaconda 3, Windows
- Compiled with PyInstaller --onedir

What I've tried:

- Tried downgrading PyInstaller to 2.1 as suggested here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3916 but doesn't work as Python 3 is not supported
- Was originally on PyInstaller 3.5, upgraded to dev version as suggested under some of the issues on PyInstaller github
- Tried including `--exclude-module=.git`

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
        '--name=%s' % 'Dummy App',
        '--onedir',
        '--nowindowed',
        r'--workpath=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\build7',
        r'--distpath=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\dist7',
        '--hidden-import=theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams',
        '--hidden-import=pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
        '--clean',
        '--add-data={0};.'.format('redacted.xml'),
        '--add-data={0};{0}'.format('redacted_folder'),
        '--add-data={0};.'.format('redacted.pdf'),
        '--exclude-module={0}'.format('.git'),
        '--log-level=WARN',
        'MainWindow.py'
    ])
```

Full stacktrace:

```
79702 DEBUG: Analyzing .git\objects\78\e83411cea88cd038acb12c005a984fc0d6d423
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
    raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/Dropbox/GitHub_Repos/DiabetesReportGenerator_v2/pyinstaller_freeze.py", line 37, in <module>
    'MainWindow.py'
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Dropbox\GitHub_Repos\DiabetesReportGenerator_v2\Risk Calculator.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 468, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects))
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 226, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 402, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 353, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1005, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\envs\ids_gui\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

P.S. Compilation and the exe functioned perfectly with virtualenv environment created from Anaconda environment earlier (without need for `--exclude-module=.git`), but was too bloated with packages because the virtualenv environment is still considered to be part of the conda environment. So I used a new conda environment, and this error appeared

I've gotten it to work by creating another virtualenv environment in this new conda environment, but that is a very roundabout way. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the same

Comment: @eggrobot78 see below, hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, PyInstaller seems to search through `.git` folder and `redacted_folder` unnecessarily

I solved this problem by:

1. MOVING the folder(s) out of the directory *before freezing*
2. Additionally, if the folder is required for the frozen app to run (e.g. as a data folder), I would also either:

   - Comment / remove the corresponding part for `--add-data` and manually copy the folder over, or
   - Change the path for `--add-data` e.g. if you moved `redacted_folder` to your Desktop, you can change to `'--add-data=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/redacted_folder'`

You'll still need `.git` and `redacted_folder` back in the original directory to use Git and run your code without freezing

---

For example, I had trouble with `.git` and `redacted_folder`. The frozen executable needed `redacted_folder` to run parts of the code.

What I did was:

1. Move `.git` and `redacted_folder` to a separate directory
2. Then, I commented out the line to add data for `redacted_folder`:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
        '--name=%s' % 'Dummy App',
        '--onedir',
        '--nowindowed',
        r'--workpath=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\build7',
        r'--distpath=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\dist7',
        '--hidden-import=theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams',
        '--hidden-import=pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
        '--clean',
        '--add-data={0};.'.format('redacted.xml'),
        # Remove `redacted_folder` and comment out the following line
        # '--add-data={0};{0}'.format('redacted_folder'),
        '--add-data={0};.'.format('redacted.pdf'),
        '--exclude-module={0}'.format('.git'),
        '--log-level=WARN',
        'MainWindow.py'
    ])
```

3. After freezing, I copied `redacted_folder` over to the appropriate location relative to the frozen executable in `distpath`

Answer (score 3):

I installed pyinstaller in a new conda environment using pip, however pywin32 did not get installed by default (eventhough documentation mentioned it would). Installing it fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 3):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4467). Update PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found another thread where somebody uninstalled Python and then reinstalled Python to fix it.

The *key* information to understand the problem though, was that they had *originally* installed Python using Microsoft Store. When they reinstalled Python, they just downloaded Python from python.org and this took care of the problem. It worked for me too.

It seems very likely that something in the Microsoft Store version is causing problems like this.

Comment: Interesting if that's the case for some people, though mine was installed via Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Start from administrator cmd or ide and try again, it's helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Running from Jupyter Notebook with elevated privilegies worked for me!